# Extract a word that follows a particular word from a webpage with python

Tags: python, web, scripting

I am writing a simple web scraper script to extract a single word from a web page. The word I require changes regularly, but comes after a word that never changes, so I can search for it.

This my script so far:

```
#!/bin/python

import requests
response = requests.get('http://vpnbook.com/freevpn')
print(response.text)
```

Which obviously prints the whole HTML of the page. But the bit I need is the password:

```
<li>All bundles include UDP53, UDP 25000, TCP 80, TCP 443 profile</li>
<li>Username: <strong>vpnbook</strong></li>
<li>Password: <strong>binbd5ar</strong></li>
</ul>
```

How could I print **ONLY** 'binbd5ar' (or whatever replaces it) to STOUT?

Comment: Look into HTML parsing. Stuff like BeautifulSoup or LXML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

response = requests.get('http://vpnbook.com/freevpn')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
pricing = soup.find(id = 'pricing')
first_column = pricing.find('div', {'class': 'one-third'})
for li in first_column.find('ul', {'class': 'disc'}):
    if 'password' in str(li).lower():
        password = li.find('strong').text
print(password)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
re.search(r'Password: <strong>(.+)</strong>',response.text).group(1)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Imparting the underlying logic is more important than just giving the code, because it helps the OP and other readers fix this and similar issues themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex search.

"Python offers two different primitive operations based on regular expressions: re.match() checks for a match only at the beginning of the string, while re.search() checks for a match anywhere in the string"
[link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match)

```
>>> import re
>>> x = re.search(r"Password: <strong>(?P<pass>\w+)</strong>", response.text)
>>> print x.groupdict()
{'pass': 'binbd5ar'}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
password = re.match(r'Password: <strong>(.*?)</strong>',response.text).group(1)
```

then to change it

```
re.sub(password,newPassword,response.text,max = 1)
```

Comment: @R Nar -1 is not from me, but your code does not work, try it yourself

Comment: my bad, i dont know why i put in [\.], that should just be . (i edited it)

Comment: @R Nar  Still does not work. "Match" is not appropriate here. See the documentation on match "If zero or more characters _at the beginning of string_ match the regular expression pattern, return a corresponding MatchObject instance".