# ImportError: cannot import name 'BeautifulSoup' , bs4 installed already

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying the following code from one thread on stackverflow - [Extract a word that follows a particular word from a webpage with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32894497/extract-a-word-that-follows-a-particular-word-from-a-webpage-with-python)

I have named the file multiple things like s.py symantec.py

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

response = requests.get('http://vpnbook.com/freevpn')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
pricing = soup.find(id = 'pricing')
first_column = pricing.find('div', {'class': 'one-third'})
for li in first_column.find('ul', {'class': 'disc'}):
    if 'password' in str(li).lower():
        password = li.find('strong').text
print(password)
```

I am facing the following error -

```
python s.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "s.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  File "C:\Users\Abhinav\Documents\automation\bs4.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: cannot import name 'BeautifulSoup'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change the name of your file that is **'bs4.py'**.

```
"C:\Users\Abhinav\Documents\automation\bs4.py"
```

Change it to something else because bs4.py is using by BeautifulSoup itself.

---

Also  Just go to your python file where it is installed  C:\python\Lib\site-packages and then copy bs4 and beautifulsoup4-4.6.0.dist-info folders and paste it to your project folder where you have saved your working project.

Comment: Copying dist info is not necessary.

Comment: Please go for the second solution and copy as I instructed.

Comment: In your case, it found a file called bs4.py in the same directory where it was being executed, and since it matches what you are trying to import - Python stopped searching the rest of the directories.

As your own bs4.py does not contain the object BeautifulSoup, you get the import error.

This sort of name clashing can be avoided by careful naming of your files; it does come in useful in some cases (for example when you are trying to mock or override some modules); but that is not the case here.